# Android: BitmapFactory.decodeFile / OpenCV does return invaild Bitmap

Tags: android, opencv, bitmapfactory

I'm taking a picture with the camera activity and then try to read it from the saved location. Unfortunately the Bitmap returnd by:

```
Bitmap bimage = BitmapFactory.decodeFile( path );
```

has height and width = -1. 
I'm using OpenCV and when I read the image with

```
Mat img = Highgui.imread(path);
```

I get a proper matrix. Altough I cannot convert it to a bitmap. When doing

```
bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(img.cols(), img.rows(), Config.ARGB_8888);
Utils.matToBitmap(img, bmp);
```

I get the same result again: A Bitmap with width and height = -1. Do I need to watch out for the image format? Can I set that on the camera intent? Shouldn't

```
BitmapFactory.decodeFile( path );
```

automatically realize what the format is?

I'm running this on a Samsung galaxy S with Android 2.3.1 and OpenCV 2.3.1

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Samsung has some issues with camera intent http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7031374/photo-capture-intent-causes-nullpointerexception-on-samsung-phones-only/7031422#7031422

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Samsung has some issues with camera intent [Photo capture Intent causes NullPointerException on Samsung phones only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7031374/photo-capture-intent-causes-nullpointerexception-on-samsung-phones-only/7031422#7031422)

Try this way

// to call camera

```
String _path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                    + File.separator + "TakenFromCamera.png";
            File file = new File(_path);
            Uri outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
            Intent intent = new Intent(
                    android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri);
            startActivityForResult(intent, 1212);
```

// in activity onResult

```
if (requestCode == 1212) {
            String _path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                    + File.separator + "TakenFromCamera.png";
            mBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(_path);
            if (mBitmap == null) {
            } else {
                Intent intent = new Intent(AYGCamActivity.this,
                        myGalleryImage.class);

                startActivity(intent);
            }

        }
```

Comment: Thanks. That worked :). I pretty much did that, except that I used the ending .jpg. Do you think this might caused the problem, as then the decoder tried to decode a JPEG when it was actually a PNG...